# I am using MIPS simulator to calculate the sum of numbers from N (10 in my case) to 1

Tags: recursion, stack, mips, system-calls

I tried with the following code, but the answer is wrong. It should be 55 but i got 10. any help folks?

```
main:
# initialize values to 3 registers
addi $a0,$zero,10    
jal sum  # call method

# Print out the summation upto 10 
li $v0,1        # print integer

add $a1,$v0,$zero   #load return value into argument 
syscall

li $v0,10  # Exit
syscall

sum:    

addi    $sp,$sp,-8      #   allocate space  on  stack   
sw  $ra,0($sp)      #   store   the return  address 
sw  $a0,4($sp)      #   store   the argument    

slti    $t0,$a0,1       #   check   if  n   >   0   
beq $t0,$0,recurse      #   n   >   0   case    
add $v0,$0,$0       #   start   return  value   to  0   
addi    $sp,$sp,8       #   pop 2   items   off stack   
jr  $ra         #   return  to  caller  

recurse:    
addi    $a0,$a0,-1      #   calculate   n-1 
jal sum         #   recursively call    sum(n-1)    

lw  $ra,0($sp)      #   restore saved   return  address 
lw  $a0,4($sp)      #   restore saved   argument    
addi    $sp,$sp,8       #   pop 2   items   off stack   

add $v0,$a0,$v0     #   calculate   n   +   sum(n-1)    
jr  $ra         #   return  to  caller
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [the answer is always wrong in this MIPS recursion . got 10, supposed to be 55](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727014/the-answer-is-always-wrong-in-this-mips-recursion-got-10-supposed-to-be-55)

Comment: any help ? on whats wrong wit the code?

Comment: If you don't get an answer to [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727014/the-answer-is-always-wrong-in-this-mips-recursion-got-10-supposed-to-be-55), don't ask it again. Either wait a bit or edit the original question with more information. Asking a second time won't get you anything more than asking once.

Comment: hey mate! i just indeed, made the question clear. and i have got my assignments due, waiting for more than 2 hrs might not be a good option!

Comment: If you're looking to clarify the question, it's better to do so by editing your original question. I have copied your clarifications here into your original question. There's unfortunately nothing we can do about your assignments being due; as I said, asking a second time won't help any more than asking once. Anyone who can offer you guidance will be able to help just as well with one question as with two. Asking again actually makes it less likely for you to get help, because information will be split into two places instead of one.

Comment: ok then, i gotta keep waiting.

Comment: Here's my advice. Sit down with a pen and paper and execute every instruction in turn with that wetware inside your skull, writing down any changes to memory or registers. Then you'll be able to see _exactly_ where it goes wrong.

Comment: paxdiablo, i tried man but i am not sure what is not working. any help>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving the sum from `$v0` to `$a1` after you store 1 in `$v0`.

Also, You are storing the sum in `$a1`, while  `$a0` is the register that gets printed..

```
add $a1,$v0,$zero   #load return value into argument 
      ^ HERE
```

This should fix it.

```
add $a0,$v0,$zero   #load return value into argument 
li $v0,1        # print integer
syscall
```